# UILongPressGestureRecognizer not calling its target method

Tags: ios, delegates, uigesturerecognizer, ios12, uilongpressgesturerecogni

This worked with devices on iOS 11, but with my device updated to iOS 12 it no longer works:

```
//the viewcontroller is initiated with UIGestureRecognizerDelegate

let longPressGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(longPress))

//in cellForRowAt:
longPressGesture.minimumPressDuration = 1.0
longPressGesture.delegate = self
longPressGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = false
cell.addGestureRecognizer(longPressGesture)

@objc func longPress(longPressGestureRecognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
     //never called
}
```

I also tried adding the gesture recognizer to a button in viewDidLoad to ensure it wasn't an issue with the tableview, and the longPress function is still not getting called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> //the viewcontroller is initiated with UIGestureRecognizerDelegate
> let longPressGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(longPress))
> ```

It looks like you are trying to make `longPressGesture` an instance property of your UIViewController while giving it a target and action as part of its initializer. That's not going to work, because at the time it is initialized, the target, `self`, is not the instance. There is no instance yet; the instance is what we are in the middle of creating!

Instead, move that line into `cellForRowAt:`, like this:

```
//in cellForRowAt:
let longPressGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(longPress))
longPressGesture.minimumPressDuration = 1.0
longPressGesture.delegate = self
longPressGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = false
cell.addGestureRecognizer(longPressGesture)
```

Comment: This was the correct reason for the issue I was facing, although my solution was a bit different because I still need to declare longPressGesture as an instance property so I can add/remove it later on as needed. So still creating it as an instance property buy I am now defining its target elsewhere in the code when self is able to be accessed. Thanks for your help here!

Comment: Exactly right. It doesn't matter when you set the target as long as you don't do it as part of the instance property default initializer!